# How to Modify ionic popup background at run time

Tags: android, iphone, ionic-framework, ionic-popup

I created a custom popup in ionic if I change the background color of popup class from CSS background color of all other popups is changed. I want to change the background color of only my custom popup.

Comment: I am also facing same issue.

Comment: try with ng-class.

Comment: how ?its work for you. @the_mahasagar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was created custom CSS for my popup in show method like

```
$ionicPopup.show({
  template: '',
  title: '',
  subTitle: '',
  cssClass: 'myPopup',
  scope: $scope,
  ...
```

And My Custom CSS is as follows

```
.myPopup .popup{
    //write your code here
} 

.myPopup .popup-body{
    // Write your css here
}
```

this was worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `cssClass` to the `$ionicPopup.show` method:

```
$ionicPopup.show({
      template: '',
      title: '',
      subTitle: '',
      cssClass: 'myPopup',
      scope: $scope,
      ...
```

and this class will appear in the generated html as shown here:
[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: But How to write CSS class which overwrites the system classes

Comment: You must be having a css file for your project, there you add this class `.myPopup .popup { background-color: red }`.